# Cocoa-Touch – Dismiss modal viewcontroller and pop viewcontroller at the same time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

How can I achieve this? Basically I have first a view controller that lists some items, if I touch one Item it will push another viewcontroller on the stack for a detailed view of that item, then if I choose "edit" it will present a modal viewcontroller, in this modal view controller I have the option to delete the item. If I choose to delete I want to dismiss the modal view controller and be taken back to the lists of items.

So for clarity ListViewController, DetailedViewController, EditViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the DetailedViewController for editing as well, like the Contacts.app.

If you don't want to omit the EditViewController, then you could solve it with a delegate pattern, which pops the DetailedViewController before you dismiss the edit controller.

Comment: How would you go from Detailed -> Edit with a nice animation like in the Contacts.app ?

Comment: Depends on your view, but if you have a tableview, the editing methods would be your queue for executing animations in the correct order.

Comment: Cocoa with love has a nice post which would provide som hints: [Editing tableviews](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html)